# Impossible to set proxy settings in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

By trying to change the parameters of the proxy in google chrome, going to Parameters -> system -> Open the proxy parameters, then in the connections tab, I see that the network parameter button is disabled with a message at the bottom indicating: "Some parameters are managed by your system administrator".

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: this is a programming question?

Comment: No, but when the launches the browser, and I enter url of any site, I get msg 'There is no internet connection'', so i go to verify and set the proxy adress but i cant